# Interpreting GPU information from Process Explorer

Tags: memory-leaks, directx, gpu, sharpdx, process-explorer

I am trying to hunt down a possible memory leak in my Sharpdx / DirectX application.

I am getting the following information from process explorer which I do not know how to interpret.

[image]

1. What is Dedicated GPU Memory?
2. What is System GPU Memory?
3. What is Comitted GPU Memory?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1. Dedicated GPU memory is basically the VRAM on-board the GPU
2. System GPU memory is memory that the graphics card driver is using the GART (*Graphics Address Remapping Table*) to store resources in system memory... AGP and PCI Express both provide regions of memory set aside for this purpose (sometimes referred to as aperture segments).
3. Committed GPU memory refers to the amount of memory mapped into a display device's address space by the display driver, it is a difficult concept to explain but this number typically does not represent anything worthwhile to anyone but driver developers.

I suggest you look into the [following documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538322%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as well as [this overview of GPU address space segementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff570136%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), while they are somewhat technical they give a general overview of what is going on.